# Can Gson produce XML?

Tags: java, xml, json, serialization, gson

Is it possible to use the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to produce XML?

I am aware the [gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml) can read XML into Gson. Is there a library that lets you go the other way?

My motivation is that I have a complex application that needs to serialise to both JSON and XML and I'd ideally like to use a single serialisation library.

Comment: [_Xstream_](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) can serialize to both Json and XML

Comment: @gkiko - thanks. However, I've found XStream to be a "poor cousin" compared to Gson. XStream is ok at best, while Gson is really well designed and a pleasure to use.

Comment: Agreed. I've been messing with _Xstream_ for 2 hours to serialize my enum  type correctly in xml. While I found _Gson_ solution in 10 mins

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if the library can serialize to both JSON and XML.

But from the same model-object, you can do it, e.g. [Jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) as XML-Serializer and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as JSON-serializer. And, if your application is complex enough to modularise, you should encapsulate serialization layer.